# if equals - как сравнить несколько значений

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
if (newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("doc")) 
{
    holder.title.setText("{fa-file-word-o}");
    holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#42aaff"));
}
else if (newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("jpg")) 
{
    //Glide.with(context).load("http://nhmt.ru"+newses.get(position).getUrl()).into(holder.mCircle);
    //Log.i(newses.get(position).getUrl(),"Nags");
    //holder.title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.title.setText("{fa-file-image-o}");
    holder.title.setTextColor(0xffa1887f);
}
else if (newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("jpeg")) 
{
    holder.title.setText("{fa-file-image-o}");
    holder.title.setTextColor(0xffa1887f);
}
else if (newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("gif")) 
{
    holder.title.setText("{fa-file-image-o}");
    holder.title.setTextColor(0xffa1887f);
}
else if (newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("bmp")) 
{
    holder.title.setText("{fa-file-image-o}");
    holder.title.setTextColor(0xffa1887f);
}
else 
{
    holder.title.setText("{fa-file-o}");
    holder.title.setTextColor(0xff90a4ae);
}
```

Как можно это сократить, ведь для всех файлов картинок я использую один и тот же параметр. 
Сократить можно только так?

```
if(newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("gif") ||newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("jpg")||newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("bmp")){
```

Или как-то в цикл залить массив?

Comment: Минимум яб эту "newses.get(position).getTitle()" перевелбы в нейкий String title = newses.get(position).getTitle(). и с ним работал.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, ну это да, не подумал .Но главное мне поменьше if а то там растянется на всю страницу

Comment: А так, это не проблема, главное в этом огромном коде ошибок не допустить. И даже переводить в String title особо и не надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как вариант, можно заюзать старый добрый `switch`:

```
   switch (getExtension(newses.get(position).getTitle())) {
        case "gif":
        case "jpeg":
        case "jpg":
        case "bmp":
            holder.title.setText("{fa-file-image-o}");
            holder.title.setTextColor(0xffa1887f);
            break;
        case "doc":
            holder.title.setText("{fa-file-word-o}");
            holder.title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#42aaff"));
            break;
        default:
            holder.title.setText("{fa-file-o}");
            holder.title.setTextColor(0xff90a4ae);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Опять же, для андроид такое не прокатит.

Comment: в андройде нет switch? очень сомневаюсь

Comment: `switch` для строковых значений появился в Java 7

Comment: а там что шестая? тяжко вам ребята, но вы держитесь).

Comment: да, изначально кастрированная java 6. 
хотя вот что нашёл: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480090/does-android-support-jdk-6-or-7, так что я не особо прав оказался :)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы как-то так сделал. Ещё стоит вынести константы типа `{fa-file-image-o}` и `0xffa1887f` в отдельные переменные, для улучшения читабельности кода.

```
String[] extensions = new String[]{"jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp"};
int color;
String text;
if(Stream.of(extensions).anyMatch(s -> newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith(s))){
    text = "{fa-file-image-o}";
    color = 0xffa1887f;
} else if (newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("doc")) {
    text = "{fa-file-word-o}";
    color = Color.parseColor("#42aaff");
} else {
    text = "{fa-file-o}";
    color = 0xff90a4ae;
}
holder.title.setText(text);
holder.title.setTextColor(color);
```

P.S. если это код для Android и библиотек эмулирующих Stream API вы не используете, то вместо

```
Stream.of(extensions).anyMatch(s -> newses.get(position).getTitle().endsWith(s)
```

можно поизвращаться:

```
Arrays.asList(extensions).contains(getExtension(newses.get(position).getTitle()));
```

где `getExtension` можно взять из `apache.commons.io`

```
public static String getExtension(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int index = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (index == -1) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return filename.substring(index + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: выглядит классно, спасибо ))) ради одного класса не стоит подключать библиотеку? лучше сократить так  ведь есть не только doc есть docx

Comment: Да, библиотеку не стоит подключать, можно просто метод себе скопипастить.